# How does join work on ruby threads?

Tags: ruby, multithreading

Calling `join` on a thread will block the parent thread while the thread to be joined has not finished. To check this, I created this code:

```
threads = []
3.times do |i|
  threads << Thread.new do
    3.times do |j|
      puts "Thread #{i} says #{j} (#{Thread.current})"
      sleep 0.1
    end
  end
end

#threads.map(&:join)
threads[0].join
puts "After first join"
threads[1].join
puts "After second join"
threads[2].join
puts "Last line of main thread"
```

Running such code gives this output:

```
Thread 0 says 0 (#<Thread:0x007fdceb0b8568>)
Thread 2 says 0 (#<Thread:0x007fdce982bb08>)
Thread 1 says 0 (#<Thread:0x007fdceb0b8450>)
Thread 0 says 1 (#<Thread:0x007fdceb0b8568>)
Thread 1 says 1 (#<Thread:0x007fdceb0b8450>)
Thread 2 says 1 (#<Thread:0x007fdce982bb08>)
Thread 1 says 2 (#<Thread:0x007fdceb0b8450>)
Thread 2 says 2 (#<Thread:0x007fdce982bb08>)
Thread 0 says 2 (#<Thread:0x007fdceb0b8568>)
After first join
After second join
Last line of main thread
```

Why did ruby print `After first join` after threads' instructions although the instruction `threads[1].join` was executed after this print instruction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the `puts "Thread #{i} says #{j} (#{Thread.current})"` part (or perhaps all) of `threads[1]` finished before `puts "After first join"`. The fact that `threads[1].join` was executed after `puts "After first join"` does not affect the result.

You seem to have two points of logic flaw. They should be corrected as follows:

- If `puts "Thread #{i} says #{j} (#{Thread.current})"` of `threads[1]` was done before `puts "After first join"` of the main thread, then whether the entire `threads[1]` was done before  `puts "After first join"` started is irrelevant.
- `threads[1]` has chance to be done before  `puts "After first join"` of the main thread was executed. `threads[1].join` shows effect only otherwise.

And what is likely to happen (which actually did happen) is that, since you have `threads[0].join` before any `puts` method calls, the main thread was sleeping until `threads[0]` finished. And since `threads[1]`, and `threads[2]` started immediately after `threads[0]`, the three sub-threads finished roughly at almost the same time. In other words, if you wait enough time for `threads[0]` to finish, then it is likely that the other two threads would also be finished.

Comment: Correct. Threads doing the same thing to calculate something, should take the same time to do it. Only if there is an external influence that varies would there be a difference, like waiting for inputs on ports or accessing separate databases. Then, over time, we'd probably see drift. (We can simulate that uneven load using randomized sleep times in the threads if necessary.)